# Line Chart in ReCharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recharts

I have a data set which looks like this:

```
data = [
  { value: 0, timeStamp: Wed Jun 15 2022 00:00:00 },
  { value: 0, timeStamp: Wed Jun 15 2022 01:00:00 },
  { value: 0, timeStamp: Wed Jun 15 2022 02:00:00 },
  { value: 0, timeStamp: Wed Jun 15 2022 03:00:00 }
];
```

This dataset is dynamic and I want to show a Line Chart with value on Y-Axis and TimeStamp on XAxis

It should look something like this:
[image]

And this is a code that I have written using ReCharts in ReactJS:

```
<LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}>
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="value" stroke="#8884d8" />
    <XAxis dataKey="timestamp" />
    <YAxis dataKey="value" />
</LineChart>
```

Using the above code I am not able to draw the plot points on the graph. Where am I missing?

Comment: XAxis dataKey value timestamp is misspelled...it should be timeStamp...